# WordPress RSS feeds get date is UTC time

Tags: php, wordpress, date, rss

I'm developing a widget in Wordpress to import sport scores through a RSS feed. The RSS feed items have a  which is the match date and time, so it's really important information. The  item in the RSS feed look likes this: [ Sat, 14 Nov 2015 15:00:00 +0100 ], but when I want to get this date in a variable with:

```
$date = $item->get_date();
```

I'm getting the following output: 14 November 2015, 2:00 pm

The right time should be 15:00 (local). Does anybody know how I can get the right time from the RSS feed?

```
$rss = fetch_feed('http://www.volleybal.nl/application/handlers/export.php?format=rss&type=vereniging&programma=7141&iRegionId=7000');

if (!is_wp_error($rss)) : // Checks that the object is created correctly
    // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 5. 
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity();

    // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
endif;

foreach ($rss_items as $item) :
     $splitby = array('Wedstrijd:', 'Datum:', 'Speellocatie:');
     $text = esc_html($item->get_description());
     $split = explode(' ', $text);
     $result = array();
     $temp = array();
     $date = strtotime($item->get_date());
     $day = date('j M', $date);
     $time = date('G:i', $date);
 endforeach;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, will that timezone always be CET?

Comment: Your'e getting the 'right time'. `[ Sat, 14 Nov 2015 15:00:00 +0100 ]` is 3pm + 1, aka 4pm. Basically the string is giving the time in UTC, +1. What time zone do you want?

Comment: I saw I made a mistake in the explanation. The time in the item is 15:00:00 +0100 and when I get the date with `$item->get_date()` I receive 2:00 pm.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yes, it will always be CET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution at: https://geek.hellyer.kiwi/2012/08/04/convert-utc-to-local-time-in-wordpress/

```
/*
* Converts UTC time to local time as set in WordPress
* Processes data in the format "Y-m-d H:i:s" (same format as used in WordPress core)
*
* @author Ryan Hellyer <ryanhellyer@gmail.com>
*/
function convert_time( $time ) {
$timestamp = strtotime( $time ); // Converting time to Unix timestamp
$offset = get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * 60 * 60; // Time offset in seconds
$local_timestamp = $timestamp + $offset;
$local_time = date_i18n( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $local_timestamp );
return $local_time;
}

$time = '2012-08-03 12:33:07';
echo convert_time( $time );
```